# In Material themes blurry text while renaming files

Tags: themes, mate

I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 Mate Desktop. I noticed recently that `Caja` file manager shows blurry and intermingled characters while renaming file or folders in some themes.
I currently have `Materia-Dark-Compact` theme, that's what it looks like:

[image]

Is there a `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` trick that I can use?

**EDIT**:
I tested installed themes one by one.

All of the `Material` themes look buggy:

```
Yuyo-Dark OK
Yuyo      OK
Radiant-Mate OK
Menta  OK
Materia-Light-Compact Buggy
Materia-Light Buggy
Materia-Dark-Compact Buggy 
Green-Submarine OK
Green-Laguna OK
Blue-Submarine OK
Blue-Menta OK
Black-Mate OK
Ambiant-Mate-Dark OK
Ambiant-Mate OK
```

Comment: In which themes do you see the problem, in which not? Adding information on your hardware also may be useful.